# Legacy mode Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

Is there a legacy mode for Cocoapods that allows a user to use a version of Cocoapods as if it was an older one? Eg use 1.0.0 as if it was 0.39 via a command line argument to avoid downloading legacy versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the version to be installed. However, there is nothing wrong with having multiple versions installed. You can also delete them if you no longer need a specific version.

Once installed, run the version you want with this:

```
pod _0.39.0_ YourCommandHere
```

Change the version number as needed.